# Angular datepicker, can't set default date without ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-material, angular-moment

I'm using FormBuilder to generate my forms, but I can't set a default date value to the date inputs (in some cases I need a pre-established date for these forms, i.e edit forms)

Using FormGroup's setValue function won't work, I was able to get it working by binding a ngModel to the datepicker input, but doesn't feel like the correct way of doing.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h45fid

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  datef: [this.today.toISOString(), [Validators.required]],
  dateng: [{ value: moment(this.today).valueOf() }, [Validators.required]],
});

OR

this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  datef: [moment(this.today).toISOString(), [Validators.required]],
  dateng: [{ value: moment(this.today).valueOf() }, [Validators.required]],
});
```

Reference : [example_in_documentation](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxvbqolqrqo?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.ts)